# Centos 6; phpMyAdmin 'Cannot log in to the MySQL server' after moving mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, unix, centos6, socket, phpmyadmin

I recently moved my mysql `datadir` from `/var/lib/mysql` to a new directory `/home/mysql` mounted on a new hard drive.

For neatness sake I thought it'd be nice to place the `tmpdir` and `socket` on this new hard drive.

Everything works as planned, until I moved the socket file. Moving the socket file prevents phpMyAdmin from logging in; I can login fine from the command line and using my web framework, just not with phpMyAdmin.

The only difference between a working configuration and not is in my `my.cnf` file..

Working:

```
[mysqld]
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

...

[client]
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Not:

```
[mysqld]
socket = /home/mysql/mysql.sock 

...

[client]
socket = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Assuming this is a permissions error I checked the paths of each location:

```
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  var
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  lib
drwxr-xr-x  mysql mysql mysql
srwxrwxrwx  mysql mysql mysql.sock

drwxr-xr-x. root  root  home
drwxr-xr-x  mysql mysql mysql
srwxrwxrwx  mysql mysql mysql.sock
```

so I'm guessing they are OK. Have I assumed wrong?

I phpMyAdmin configured to use `'localhost'` I have the mysql `bind-address` option set to our local network IP for the server (192.168.etc.)

I also restarted both the `httpd` and `mysqld` servers when testing a new config.

I'm quite happy to leave the socket file where it is, assuming this isn't a security/performance issue, but would love to know what is going on if anyone can help shed some light!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use the built-in default location PHP also needs to be explicitly configured with the location of the MySQL socket file in the php.ini file or in the connection string...

[`pdo_mysql.default_socket`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)`= /home/mysql/mysql.sock`

or  depending on your choice of API's

[`mysqli.default_socket`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-socket)`= /home/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Yours is probably the best answer because it covers the connection default for all PHP applications, however phpMyAdmin also allows one to configure the socket path directly, in `config.inc.php` with the directive `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']  = '/home/mysql/mysql.sock';`

Answer (score 0):

As *ibennetch* suggested in his comment above, setting the socket path to the new location woks. In my case the default setting for connection type was **'tcp'**. That also needs to be changed to **'socket'**.

Thus the two lines that need to be changed in the **config.in.php** file are:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/home/mysql/mysql.sock';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
```

Don't forge to restart httpd:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```